# Streaming Jobs and tables consistency

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, etl, spark-structured-streaming

I have been assigned the task to create a data streaming pipeline to move data from mysql to a datalake.

To achieve this task, I have created a pipeline using Debezium, Kafka and Spark Structured Streaming.

Debezium writes all the events to a single kafka topic.

The Spark job uses the `forEachBatch` function, it reads events, divides them by table, and makes sure to upsert events in each corresponding table using Delta.

One tough requirement to implement is that this data should be directly queried by data consumers, it is a tough requirement because due to grouping upserts by table I am changing the events order (performing upserts in an ordered way for each individual transaction would be extremely inefficient). This could lead to potential data inconsistencies because during the batch processing time some tables are more updated than others.

One way to mitigate this issue I came up with is to let users access these tables only through athena/snowflake, this way I can decouple what data I am showing from what data is actually inside the table by using the [symlink manifest files](https://docs.delta.io/latest/presto-integration.html#set-up-the-presto-trino-or-athena-to-delta-lake-integration-and-query-delta-tables). This is a workaround and not a definitive solution, because it minimizes the time tables are inconsistent to the time it takes to refresh all the manifests.

Is there any better way to achieve consistency between tables in a streaming system?

I am also tempted to reduce inconsistency by minimizing latency , creating append-only tables, but I am afraid these tables will start growing exponentially.

Comment: What types of queries are you running? Databases like Druid or Pinot, Clickhouse, Couchbase, all offer native Kafka ingest. Therefore, you wouldn't need Spark or Delta filesystem. Then aggregations are handled directly at the database level via a compactor and ordering is handled at query time. Or for more simple use cases, ksqlDB could be used.

Comment: @OneCricketeer the goal here is to have a consistent replica of our source db with the lowest possible latency, the goal is to let data consumers build reports on top of such data. We have two requirements: first is data should not go directly into any target system, so landing on S3 is not optional, second we don't have to maintain any infrastructure because the team is still very small, so the suggested tools cannot be used

Comment: I never suggested S3. That'll definitely be the slowest. If you want fast queries for reports, you'll need to use a system that supports indexing, which Spark does not offer. Delta may support Bloom filters, but may not assist with analytics. You can try finding a hosted solution of those systems. For example, StarTree offers hosted [Pinot](https://docs.pinot.apache.org/). Or load data into AWS Opensearch, or Google BiqQuery, etc.